# Images of filters need not be a filter

Tags: filters

My question is the following:

> Let $f$ be a mapping of a set $X$ into a set $Y$ and $\mathcal{F}$ a filter on $X$. Why is it that  $f\left(\mathcal{F}\right)=\{f[F]:F\in\mathcal{F}\}$ is not a filter on $Y$ if $f$ is not surjective?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If $A \supset f[F]$ there is no reason to $A \in f(\mathcal{F})$.

Answer (score 1):

E.g. $Y$ must be in any filter on $Y$ (it's a superset of any set) but is only in $f(\mathcal{F})$ if $f$ is surjective. In general the superset axiom need not be fulfilled, but it *is* always a filterbase, so adding all supersets of sets from $f(\mathcal{F})$ *will* give us a filter on $Y$.